# Only able to login ONCE with Selenium and Django Testing

Tags: django, selenium, webdriver, django-testing

I'm testing using Django's tests and Selenium so I can run tests with a live browser. But it won't let me log in more then once.

I am using Django's `StaticLiveServerTestCase` to access both static and media files live. I login by going to the page. I've tried putting the login code both in `setUpClass` to run once at the beginning and `setUp` to run each time. Both only let me log in once.

Here's the code:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from selenium import webdriver

@override_settings(DEBUG=True) 
class LoginTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(cls):
    super().setUpClass()

    # create user
    cls.user = User.objects.create_user( 'Testing User', 'somewhere@wherever.com', 'pwd')

    # initalize webdriver
    cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome() # doesn't work on FireFox either
    cls.driver.set_window_size(1280,800)
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # login - send username and password to login page
    cls.driver.get(cls.live_server_url+'/accounts/login/')
    cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    username = cls.driver.find_element_by_name('login')
    username.clear()
    username.send_keys(cls.user.username)
    password = cls.driver.find_element_by_name('password')
    password.clear()
    password.send_keys("pwd")
    password.submit() # eubmits form

  @classmethod
  def tearDownClass(cls):
    cls.driver.quit() # quit after tests have run
    super().tearDownClass()

  def test_login_one(self): # this test PASSES
    self.driver.get(self.live_server_url) # go to home page
    login_menu = self.driver.find_element_by_id('login_menu')
    self.assertTrue(
        # if logged in username is in text of #login_menu
        self.user.username in login_menu.text
    )

  def test_login_two(self): # this test FAILS
    self.driver.get(self.live_server_url) # go to home page
    login_menu = self.driver.find_element_by_id('login_menu')
    self.assertTrue(
        # if logged in username is in text of #login_menu
        self.user.username in login_menu.text
    )
```

This code logs in once at the beginning. But I've also tried code that logs in each time a test is run (using `setUp` instead of 'setUpClass') and it still only lets me log in once.

Any idea what's going on?

**Update:**
I tried logging in a second time on `test_log_in_two` (the 2nd test) and I saw a "username and password not found" error in the chrome window.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve here is the capability of log in twice which is possible you just have to make a simple check inside your test method for presence of element after login happened, an if found you can simply logout and let the remaining code do it's work. Let me show you with a template what I am trying to say here :

```
@override_settings(DEBUG=True) 
class LoginTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            super().setUpClass()
            logInFunction()

    @classmethod
        def tearDownClass(cls):
            cls.driver.quit() # quit after tests have run
            super().tearDownClass()

    def test_login_one(self): # this test PASSES
        if checkForAlreadyLoggedInElement() :
            call logoutFunction()
        logInFunction()
        self.assertTrue(checkForAlreadyLoggedInElement())

    def test_login_two(self):
        if checkForAlreadyLoggedInElement() :
            call logoutFunction()
        logInFunction()
        logoutFunction()
        logInFunction()
        self.assertTrue(checkForAlreadyLoggedInElement())
```

Hope the template clears the picture on how you should proceed. Let me know if you have any other doubts.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I'm actually getting a "username and password are not correct error on the 2nd login"

Comment: @JeremyS. : Was this expected condition. If yes then you need to update the assert as per condition. Otherwise it's an issue which you need to inform if this keeps on happening after checking multiple times.